# Mapping PHP script and file dependency structure

Tags: php

I have recently become an intern on a startup online classroom system. So now, I'm scrambling to learn the system, and get to know the code for the program, which is written in PHP. This program spans around 3000 PHP files and associated images, html pages, CSS files and so forth, across over a hundred folders.

I was wondering if there was some program or utility that could parse the files and directories and create a map of sorts, showing which PHP files include which other files, so that I could see quickly which files and scripts are no longer in use or obsolete, and which files depend on other files, and so forth. In other words, I can see the file and directory structure. I would now like to see the dependency structure, in terms of includes. Without having to open each file individually and track down the `includes` statements.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly what you want, but the "[inclued](http://php.net/manual/en/book.inclued.php)" PECL extension is almost certainly going to help you.  It works on a per-request basis, and maps out the file inclusion chain.  It can even make pretty graphs!

Because it works on a request basis, unfortunately it can't map out your entire codebase for you.